# React and MUI: How to fix the MobileDateRangePicker start date to current date and not allow to change it?

Tags: reactjs

How to fix the MobileDateRangePicker start date to current date and not allow to change it in the following code?

```
import { MobileDateRangePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/lab';
.....
  <LocalizationProvider .....>
    <MobileDateRangePicker
      startText="Start"
      endText="End"
      .....
      renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <TextField {...startProps} />
          <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> - </Box>
          <TextField {...endProps} />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

Note: To simplify the code I used ..... notation, because in the React ... has already a meaning in the code syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by giving the start date an initial value:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState([new Date(), null]);
```

2. Set only `endDate` on change:

```
function handleChange([newStartDate, newEndDate]) {
  console.log(newEndDate);
  setValue(([startDate]) => [startDate, newEndDate]);
}
...
<MobileDateRangePicker
  disablePast
  startText="Start"
  endText="End"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  ...
```

3. Add `disabled` to `inputProps` of the start's `TextField`:

```
<TextField
    {...startProps}
    inputProps={{
    ...startProps.inputProps,
    disabled: true,
  }}
/>
```

4. Optional: Add the `disablePast` property to the `<MobileDateRangePicker />` component

[image: Edit ResponsiveDateRangePicker Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: With this in the calendar dialog is possible to select the start date different from this day in the date range. It is not finally saved, but can be confusing. I did this so that I used MobileDatePicker with two TextFields. The start day text field is disabled and static and contains the start date. The end day is connected only to the date picker.